# GCP Dataflow : print PCollection data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am new to GCP Dataflow, just wanted to understand if there is any way to print all values of PCollection.

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
PCollection<String> lines = p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()));
```

Here, I want to print and check all values available in lines(PCollection)

Similarly, want to access all values in words after below operation

```
PCollection<String> words = lines.apply(
            FlatMapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                    .via((String line) -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" "))));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to process the PCollection in a ParDo. [See docs here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.html). Within the ParDo you can inspect each element.

Answer (score 3):

In your main function

```
p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()))
 .apply("Print",ParDo.of(new PrintElementFn()))
```

Write a static class

```
private static class PrintElementFn extends DoFn<String,Void>{
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(@Element String input){
            System.out.println(input);
        }
    }
```